# Deregistering a script in Wordpress seems impossible

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, scripting

I tried everything. I even removed all content in functions.php and created a whole new file with just this:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
 if (is_singular()) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'gdrts-rating' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

The idea is to remove some Javascript files from my custom post type. I thought I was doing something wrong so I first tried with is_page() and even is_home(), but even that is not working for me. It seems like the code is not fired or so.

**This is my plugin:**

```
  wp_enqueue_script('gdrts-events', $this->file('js', 'events'), array(), gdrts_settings()->file_version(), false);
    wp_enqueue_script('gdrts-rating', $this->file('js', 'rating'), $depend_js, gdrts_settings()->file_version(), true);
```

So, I also tried to do it like this:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'gdrts-rating' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Not working!

Comment: Why you're not using `wp_enqueue_scripts` action?

Comment: I actually am, in a way. See updated question. This is actually what I tried to do as well.

Comment: Try change `wp_print_scripts` to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: Does not work either. I am getting frustrated. See updated answer.

Comment: You can dequeue `gdrts-events`?

Comment: What do you mean? No, I can't... I am trying also with other scripts, but it does not work for me....